# How can I let my code return the average of the numbers?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I wrote a code that would return the distance from `parse_dist(s)` and the total time `parse_time(s)`. However, I defined another function `jogging_average(activities)` that would return the distance and time for every string in `activities: list`.

Now I want to let jogging_average(activities: list) return (x+x)/(y+y) (basically the average). How can I modify my code to find the average like that??

Comment: Unrelated to your question, your parsing code (`get Digits & parse_time`) would be much simpler if you used python's regex module. If regular expressions are intimidating or unfamiliar, we were all there once. There are many good resources in the web to help learn.

Comment: For a start, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, provide a [mcve] of the code that gives you issues, along with the full output it produces and the output you'd expect instead. Also, how do you calculate the average in general? Where is the problem doing that in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def jogging_average(activities: list[str]):
    cum_dist = cum_time = 0
    for activity in activities:
        if activity.startswith("jogging"):
            cum_dist += float(parse_dist(activity))
            cum_time += parse_time(activity)
    return cum_time/cum_dist
```

Comment: cum_dist += float(parse_dist(activity))
cum_time += float(parse_time(activity))

Comment: Strictly speaking, `float(parse_time(activity))` isn't necessary, as the return result is already an `int` (and I assume OP is using python 3.x)

Comment: when i run with OP's code it gives str so float edit: yes time is in int

Comment: There's also `statistics.mean`...

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your question, on your parsing functions, you might consider

```py
import re
def parse_time(s: str) -> float:
    result = list(map(int,re.search("(?<=time:)(\d+(,\d+)?)").group(0).split(",")))
    return result[0]*60 + (0 if len(result) < 2 else result[1])

def parse_dist(s: str) -> int:
    return float(re.search("(?<=distance:)(\d+(.\d+)?)").group(0))
```